# Dashboard from Azure SQL Database

Tags: azure, dashboard, powerpivot

I have a SQL Database on Azure and I want to share some information with two friends. And so I've created 3 VIEWS with that info.

The idea is to develop an easy solution to share a dashboard.

I was thinking to:

1. Make a powerpivot with that 3 VIEWs
2. Host the powerpivot on azure (trying to schedule the refresh)
3. Develop a .xlxs with a connection string pointing to my powerpivot on azure

But the problem is.. I think that is not possible to host my powerpivot on azure and be able to schedule the refresh.

Any sugestions?

Answer (score 1):

Use powerBI! it's a complete suite of microsoft created for this problem.

the site is this : https://powerbi.microsoft.com/

You can subscribe, publish your excel and schedule refresh, you can found a tutorial to this site:

https://powerbi.microsoft.com/it-IT/documentation/powerbi-refresh-excel-file-onedrive/

Comment: Thanks for the help!
Power BI was a serious option but then I saw that I couldnt import SQL VIEWs to Power BI because I dont have the PRO version.

In that article it seems that I have an alternative.
So basically I need a dataset in excel (using Power Query) and then publish it to my OneDrive. After that I replicate that dataset on Power BI, assuming that it will force my refresh on my PowerQuery excel file every hour. Is that right?

Comment: US powerpivot and import your Views in PowerPivot. After that upload excel on your one drive and publish excel on power bi. Here the excel can be used like dataset or can be see by user. The excel can be refresh :https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Get-started-with-Power-Pivot-in-Microsoft-Excel-FDFCF944-7876-424A-8437-1A6C1043A80B?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US